# Testing if a const modal component is called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I have a footer component which has several buttons on it. All of these buttons use the `Message` const, which is an antd modal :

**Message.jsx**

```
import { Modal } from 'antd';

const { confirm } = Modal;

export const Message = (text, okayHandler, cancelHandler) => {
  confirm({
    title: text,
    okText: 'Yes',
    cancelText: 'No',
    onOk: okayHandler,
    onCancel: cancelHandler,
  });
};

export default Message;
```

**Footer.jsx**

```
class Footer extends Component {
  state = {
    from: null,
    redirectToReferrer: false,
  };

  cancelClicked = () => {
    Message('Return to the previous screen?', () => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true, from: '/home' });
    });
  };

render() {
    const { redirectToReferrer, from } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: from }} />;
    }
    return (
      <Card style={footerSyles}>
        <Button
          bounds={`${(3 * width) / 7 + (7 * width) / 84},5,${width / 7},30`}
          text="CANCEL"
          type="primary"
          icon="close"
          actionPerformed={this.cancelClicked}
        />
</Card>
//actionPerformed is actually onClick, it's taken as a prop from my <Button /> component. Card is an antd component while button is not.
```

I simply want to test when the **Button** is clicked, **cancelClicked** is called. If possible, I want to test if the state changes properly when 'OK' button is clicked on the Modal. My test is as follows, but the test fails because function is not called :

**Footer.test**

```
const defaultFooter = shallow(<Footer position="relative" bounds="10,0,775,100" />);

test('Footer should open a popup when cancel button is clicked, and redirect to home page', () => {
  const instance = defaultFooter.instance();
  const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'cancelClicked');
  instance.forceUpdate();
  const p = defaultFooter.find('Button[text="CANCEL"]');
  p.simulate('click');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I've also tried with mount rather than shallow, but the spy is still not called.

Comment: where is `Button` component coming from? it's not native `<button>`

Comment: perhaps need to replace `actionPerformed` with `onClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Common Gotchas" section for `simulate`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas) says that "even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get the onClick prop and call it."

That behavior can be seen in the `Enzyme` source code [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js#L418-L429) and [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js#L75).

So the line `p.simulate('click');` ends up trying to call the `onClick` prop of the `Button` which doesn't exist so it essentially does nothing.

[This post](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/991#issuecomment-313203726) from an Airbnb dev recommends invoking props directly and avoiding `simulate`.

In this case you would call the `actionPerformed` property directly like this:

```js
p.props().actionPerformed();
```