# Pressing onOk button clicked after Modal is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Also addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295027/testing-if-a-const-modal-component-is-called/53311959#53311959), I have a footer component which I'm trying to write tests for. The footer consists of several buttons. All of these buttons use the Message const, which is an antd modal :

EDIT : I'm still stuck in this issue. I've managed to cover this with ReactTestUtils and enzyme mount, but felt like I dived into the DOM too deep and looking for a way without using TestUtils.

**Message.jsx**

```
import { Modal } from 'antd';

const { confirm } = Modal;

export const Message = (text, okayHandler, cancelHandler) => {
  confirm({
    title: text,
    okText: 'Yes',
    cancelText: 'No',
    onOk: okayHandler,
    onCancel: cancelHandler,
  });
};

export default Message;
```

**Footer.jsx**

```
class Footer extends Component {
  state = {
    from: null,
    redirectToReferrer: false,
  };

  cancelClicked = () => {
    Message('Return to the previous screen?', () => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true, from: '/home' });
    });
  };

render() {
    const { redirectToReferrer, from } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: from }} />;
    }
    return (
      <Card style={footerSyles}>
        <MyButton
          bounds={`${(3 * width) / 7 + (7 * width) / 84},5,${width / 7},30`}
          text="CANCEL"
          type="primary"
          icon="close"
          actionPerformed={this.cancelClicked}
        />
</Card>
```

actionPerformed is actually onClick, it's taken as a prop from my  component. Card is an antd component.

I can test if the **cancelClicked** is called when the button is clicked very finely. I want to test, after calling **cancelClicked** and the modal/message has opened, when I click 'Yes' (onOk), that the state is changed. I only want to test if the state changes properly, tried to do mocks & callbacks but couldn't manage to do it. I tried to follow an approach which the mock only calls okayHandler function in Message mock.

**Footer.test**

```
    //This test works

    test('Footer should open a popup when cancel button is clicked, and redirect to home page', () => {
      const instance = defaultFooter.instance();
      const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'cancelClicked');
      instance.forceUpdate();
      const p = defaultFooter.find('MyButton[text="CANCEL"]');
      p.props().actionPerformed();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //This doesn't, where I'm trying to make 'yes' clicked or 'OkayHandler' in Message called to change the state everytime modal opens



    test('Footer should open a popup when cancel button is clicked, and redirect to home page', () => {
         jest.mock('../../utils/uiModals', () => ({
    Message: (text, okayHandler) => okayHandler(),
  }));
  const instance = defaultFooter.instance();
  instance.cancelClicked();
  expect(defaultFooter.state().from).toEqual('/home');
```

Any help will be appreciated, I'm stuck in how to solve this for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to do this by mocking, and shallow render was enough to cover this :)

**Footer.test**

```
jest.mock('../../utils/uiModals');

const defaultFooter = shallow(<Footer position="relative" bounds="10,0,775,100" />);

/*eslint-disable*/

test('Footer should open a popup when cancel button is clicked', () => {
      const instance = defaultFooter.instance();
      const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'cancelClicked');
      instance.forceUpdate();
      const p = defaultFooter.find('MyButton[text="CANCEL"]');
      p.props().actionPerformed();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

//works! yay

test('Footer should open a popup when cancel button is clicked, and redirect to home page', () => {
  const msg = require('../../utils/uiModals');
  msg.Message.mock.calls[0][1]();
  expect(defaultFooter.state().redirectToReferrer).toBeTruthy();
});
```

How I figured this out is, when I tried to call `msg.Message.mock` with expect, it gave error and recieved an object such as:

```
Received:
      object: {"calls": [["Return to the previous screen?", [Function anonymous]]
```

As stated in the jest documents, [using a mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions), I saw that the mock I declared on top of the test was recording all of it's calls. By calling `msg.Message.mock.calls[0][1]();` which held the call made in the first test, I was able to get the 'okayClicked' of the modal, and change the state. Hope this helps someone!